# Transformation between 2D coordinate systems

Tags: rigid-transformation, geometric-transformation

Let there be two coordinate systems:

1. unit coordinates at $(0,0)$, rotated by 45 degrees
2. the same, but at $(5,5)$

How would I go about to create a transformation to convert #2 coordinates into #1 coordinates?

Is it possible by multiplying standard geometric transformations, i.e. translate, scale, rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the transformations for rotation by 45 degrees, for translation by (5, 5), and for rotation by 45 degrees back again. Compose them to get the answer!

Comment: What if #1 coordinates were at (3,3)?

Comment: Same method, with one extra step.

Comment: So I'd start by translating by (-3,-3), or what?

Comment: You start with the rotation, of course! Otherwise you will be translating in the wrong direction by 45 degrees.